# spark scala "Overloaded method value select with alternatives" when trying to get the max value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
df.show
+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+----+
|     id|  val|      date|    time| use        |flag|
+-------+-----+----------+--------+------------+----+
|8200732|    1|2015-01-06|11:48:30|30065.221532|   0|
|8200733|    1|2015-01-06|11:48:40|30065.225763|   0|
|8200734|    1|2015-01-06|11:48:50|30065.229994|   0|
|8200735|    1|2015-01-06|11:49:00|30065.234225|   0|
```

I am trying to get the average use for each date value. Here is what I try:

```
 df.select("date",max($"use")).show()
<console>:26: error: overloaded method value select with alternatives:
  [U1, U2](c1: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U1], c2: org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn[org.apache.spark.sql.Row,U2])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(U1, U2)] <and>
  (col: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (String, org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have tried to re-write this many times but each time I get an error. I can get the max value for just the use but trying to get the max value of use for each date is causing me issues.

I can not use SparkSQL or pySpark for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not using either of the overloaded options for `select` method on dataframe. The one that you're using is:

```scala
df.select("date",max($"use")).show()
```

And if you notice, `"date"` is a String literal, while `max($"user")` is a `Column`. You should try to use the date column instead of literal date string:

```scala
// notice the $ before date here
df.select($"date",max($"use")).show()
```

Comment: I tried, this. It gave a different error. Ended up using  df.groupBy("date").agg(max("use")).show

Comment: @James_B that's another question, your original question is about overloading issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you should do to get the average use for each date value:

```
df.groupBy("date").agg(mean("use")).show()
```

To get max like in the question:

```
    df.groupBy("date").agg(max("use")).show()
```